# Performance issue with CUDA code, using one variable takes 100 times longer to execute

Tags: cuda, textures

I have this: (it is a mess because i'm changing every bit to see what's wrong, and what the compiler is doing)

```
__device__ inline int f(int i, int j, int value)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int delta;

    int* p = p_new_solution;
    int pitch = p_new_solution_pitch;

    int* p_row_i = (int*)((char*)p + i * pitch);
    int p_i = p_row_i[threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x];

    int* p_row_j = (int*)((char*)p + j * pitch);
    int p_j = p_row_j[threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x];

    delta =  (tex2D(A_matrix, i, i) - tex2D(A_matrix, j, j)) * (tex2D(B_matrix, p_j, p_j) - tex2D(B_matrix, p_i, p_i));
    delta += (tex2D(A_matrix, i, j) - tex2D(A_matrix, j, i)) * (tex2D(B_matrix, p_j, p_i) - tex2D(B_matrix, p_i, p_j));


    for(int k = 0 ; k < n ; k++)
    {
        int* p_row = (int*)((char*)p + k * pitch);
        int p_k = p_row[threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x];

        int A_ki = tex2D(A_matrix, k, i);
        int A_kj = tex2D(A_matrix, k, j);
        int A_ik = tex2D(A_matrix, i, k);
        int A_jk = tex2D(A_matrix, j, k);
        int B_pkpj = tex2D(B_matrix, p_k, p_j);
        int B_pkpi = tex2D(B_matrix, p_k, p_i);
        int B_pjpk = tex2D(B_matrix, p_j, p_k);
        int B_pipk = tex2D(B_matrix, p_i, p_k);

        x = (A_ki - A_kj);
        x *= (B_pkpj - B_pkpi);

        y = (A_ik - A_jk);
        y *= (B_pjpk - B_pipk);

        x += y;
    }

    x -= ( (tex2D(A_matrix, i, i) - tex2D(A_matrix, i, j)) * (tex2D(B_matrix, p_i, p_j) - tex2D(B_matrix, p_i, p_i)) ) +
           ( (tex2D(A_matrix, i, i) - tex2D(A_matrix, j, i)) * (tex2D(B_matrix, p_j, p_i) - tex2D(B_matrix, p_j, p_i)) );

    x -= ( (tex2D(A_matrix, j, i) - tex2D(A_matrix, j, j)) * (tex2D(B_matrix, p_j, p_j) - tex2D(B_matrix, p_j, p_i)) ) +
           ( (tex2D(A_matrix, i, j) - tex2D(A_matrix, j, j)) * (tex2D(B_matrix, p_j, p_j) - tex2D(B_matrix, p_j, p_j)) );


    x += delta;
    x *= 2; 

    return value;
    //return x;
}
```

The problem is with those two return statements.. if i `return value`, the whole kernel takes like `300ms`, if i `return x` it takes approximately `33000 ms`. What is the problem with this? I've tried some `__syncthreads()`, but still got the same bad time.

Those return functions aren't the final code, i need an if else statement to choose a return value, it is either gonna be `value` or `value + x`, and this if else statement is taking too long too.

Thanks for now.

Comment: Try running it in cuda-gdb (with the return value version). I expect you'll find that x, y, p, etc are not there after compilation, and in fact you won't be able to step through any lines in this function! What's annoying is that I couldn't figure out how to STOP the compiler from doing it, even compiling with different debug optimization levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time you are measuring is not the time to return a variable, it's the time to compute `x`.  NVCC detects that you have a lot of code that is doing absolutely nothing, since its results are never used if you don't return `x`.  It removes the useless code, making the function faster.

Comment: yep, i figured that out some time ago... dang.. guess it can't be faster :/

Answer (score 1):

`return value` just returns one of the arguments of the function, making the entire function a no-op.  I would guess it is entirely optimized away.  When you `return x` it does the actual work and takes 33s.